# Connecting to existing workbook throws error in xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

When I try to connect to an **existing** workbook and verify that the connection works, like so:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Workbook('/users/edchigliak/sites/xlwings/htz/google/sem_google_realizacija_2016.xlsm')

print(wb.sheet(1).name)
```

terminal on Mac OSX Yosemite throws this **error**:

> OSERROR: -1728 MESSAGE: The object you are trying to access does not
>   exist
>   COMMAND: app(u'/Applications/MicrosoftExcel.app').workbooks['sem_google_realizacija_2016.xlsm'].name.get()

Workbook **does get opened**, it prompts for a permission to enable macros and data connections, so all is well there. It seems to me as if I am trying to call a .name() method (or property?) on MicrosoftExcel.app instead of from xlwings library?

**What I ultimately wish to do (to go through the whole process):**

1. connect to this existing .xlsm
2. read 'Sheet14.RangeF:F' and 'Sheet14.RangeI:I' into a python dict
3. verify that this has been successful

Please advise how I can go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you've got the path right, e.g. try to run `open /users/edchigliak/sites/xlwings/htz/google/sem_google_realizacija_2016.xlsm` in your Terminal to see if it opens correctly.

Second, you've got the syntax wrong for the sheet. It should be like this:

```
 import xlwings as xw
 wb = xw.Workbook(...)
 print(xw.Sheet(1).name)
```

Note that it automatically refers to the last instantiated Workbook. If you want to explicitly specify the workbook, you currently need to do it like this:

```
xw.Sheet(1, wkb=wb).name
```

But this syntax might be revised in the nearer future.

Comment: Hi Felix, is there a way I can contact you directly regarding xlwings? It wont be an exhaustive in detail session I just need to explain a couple of things I'm trying to do; I believe you can take weeks of my time in just an email or two.

Comment: My email is on GitHub